# How to destroy a bootstrap if user click anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am totally new to javascript (I really mean totally). And I want to destroy a bootstrap tooltip when the highlighted text is not on focus anymore...

I tried the code below but it does not work...

```
$("body").click(function(){
            if ($(".tooltip").length){
                $("#selectme").tooltip('destroy');
            }

        });
```

I know this is very trivial and I would appreciate if someone could help me.

EDIT my question: instead of if the user clicks anywhere, changed to when the text highlighted text is not on focus anymore...

Comment: Why? The tooltip automatically hides when unfocused right?

Comment: Idk, you can also try `$("body > *")` as a selecter.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder see it here [link](http://hew.to/teste)... When I click bellow the text that is highlighted, the tooltip does not hide...

Comment: Actually what I need is to destroy the tooltip when the highlighted text is not highlighted anymore...

Comment: Works fine what's the problem?

Comment: Take a look at the following jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/2/ and see if you can use its approach to your problem.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder If you click below the highlighted text, in the middle of the whitespace between the tooltip and the footer, it does not work. Everywhere it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('focus', ':not(.tooltip)', function(){
    $('.tooltip').tooltip('hide');
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your solution solve it?